# Read DS2401 with ATmega 32 and a 1-Wire protocol

Tags: avr, atmega, 1-wire, codevision

**DS2401** is a 64-bit ROM memory that used as a hardware-serial-number. [Datasheet : [here]](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/1-wire/flash/overview/index.cfm) It has only two pin. One of them is *ground* and one of them is *Data*/*Power* pin. So for communicate with this chip there is a protocol that called **1-Wire**. [1-Wire tutorial : [here](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/1-wire/flash/overview/index.cfm) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&sqi=2&ved=0CFkQFjAJ&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fztchs.p.lodz.pl%2FInt_w_sm%2F1-wire.doc&ei=_7bKU4TMDaip4gTesYCYDQ&usg=AFQjCNH2H4E-NnoLFw_PsGLkL6NhQbkEYg&sig2=eavvP3WkxBPQG9gChtqm5Q&bvm=bv.71198958,d.bGE&cad=rja) . 
]

I want to read my **DS2401** chip with **AVR ATmega32** , and I use **1wire.h** library in **codevision**. 
As mentioned in **Codevision AVR User Manual**  [[Here]](http://www.w-r-e.de/robotik/data/software/cvavrman.pdf) I must use **w1_read()** function to read a byte of DS2401. but it returns me only `255` [On the LCD]!

This is my codevision code:

```
/*****************************************************
This program was produced by the
CodeWizardAVR V2.05.0 Professional
Automatic Program Generator
© Copyright 1998-2010 Pavel Haiduc, HP InfoTech s.r.l.
http://www.hpinfotech.com

Project : 
Version : 
Date    : 7/19/2014
Author  : 
Company : 
Comments: 


Chip type               : ATmega32A
Program type            : Application
AVR Core Clock frequency: 1.000000 MHz
Memory model            : Small
External RAM size       : 0
Data Stack size         : 512
*****************************************************/

#include <mega32a.h>
#include <delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// 1 Wire Bus interface functions
#include <1wire.h>

// Alphanumeric LCD Module functions
#include <alcd.h>

// Declare your global variables here

void main(void)
{
int init_res,read_byte,i;
char read_byte_char[64];
// Declare your local variables here

// Input/Output Ports initialization
// Port A initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
PORTA=0x00;
DDRA=0x00;

// Port B initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
PORTB=0x00;
DDRB=0x00;

// Port C initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
PORTC=0x00;
DDRC=0x00;

// Port D initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
PORTD=0x00;
DDRD=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 0 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer 0 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC0 output: Disconnected
TCCR0=0x00;
TCNT0=0x00;
OCR0=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer1 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFFFF
// OC1A output: Discon.
// OC1B output: Discon.
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: Off
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off
TCCR1A=0x00;
TCCR1B=0x00;
TCNT1H=0x00;
TCNT1L=0x00;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;
OCR1AH=0x00;
OCR1AL=0x00;
OCR1BH=0x00;
OCR1BL=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 2 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer2 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC2 output: Disconnected
ASSR=0x00;
TCCR2=0x00;
TCNT2=0x00;
OCR2=0x00;

// External Interrupt(s) initialization
// INT0: Off
// INT1: Off
// INT2: Off
MCUCR=0x00;
MCUCSR=0x00;

// Timer(s)/Counter(s) Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK=0x00;

// USART initialization
// USART disabled
UCSRB=0x00;

// Analog Comparator initialization
// Analog Comparator: Off
// Analog Comparator Input Capture by Timer/Counter 1: Off
ACSR=0x80;
SFIOR=0x00;

// ADC initialization
// ADC disabled
ADCSRA=0x00;

// SPI initialization
// SPI disabled
SPCR=0x00;

// TWI initialization
// TWI disabled
TWCR=0x00;

// 1 Wire Bus initialization
// 1 Wire Data port: PORTB
// 1 Wire Data bit: 2
// Note: 1 Wire port settings must be specified in the
// Project|Configure|C Compiler|Libraries|1 Wire IDE menu.
// w1_init(); <-------------------------

// Alphanumeric LCD initialization
// Connections specified in the
// Project|Configure|C Compiler|Libraries|Alphanumeric LCD menu:
// RS - PORTA Bit 0
// RD - PORTA Bit 1
// EN - PORTA Bit 2
// D4 - PORTA Bit 4
// D5 - PORTA Bit 5
// D6 - PORTA Bit 6
// D7 - PORTA Bit 7
// Characters/line: 16
lcd_init(16);

while (1)
      {
      init_res = w1_init();

      if (init_res ==1)
      {
         lcd_clear(); 
         lcd_gotoxy(1,0);
         lcd_puts("Chip Connected");   
         delay_ms(1000);

         lcd_clear();
         lcd_gotoxy(1,0);
         lcd_puts("Serial Number:"); 

         for (i=1;i<9;i++)
            {
               read_byte=w1_read();
               lcd_gotoxy(i,1);
               sprintf(read_byte_char,"%i",read_byte); 
               lcd_puts(read_byte_char);   
               delay_ms(1000);
            };


      }
      else
      {

        lcd_clear();
        lcd_gotoxy(1,1);
        lcd_puts("Chip Not Found");
      } 
      delay_ms(2000);
      }
}
```

**Q1: Why?**

**Q2: Each time that I call w1_read function, DS2401 send me next 1 byte? or the same first 1 byte? or total of the ROM?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're sending the ROM Command after you have initialized the bus. According to the datasheet, page 4:

> The sequence for accessing the DS2401 via the 1-Wire port is as follows:
>
> - Initialization
> - ROM Function Command
> - Read Data

The command you probably want is

**Read ROM [33h] or [0Fh]**

---

Also, are you really running at 1MHz, as stated in the auto-comment? Timing could also be the cause of these problems.

Comment: In the while loop , I used **w1-read()** after **w1-init()**. I think _w1-init()_ is the initialization command and _w1-read()_ is the **Read Rom** command.

Comment: @TheGoodUser I don't think that's quite right. IMO you're supposed to write the _Read ROM_ command using _w1_write(0x33)_, and then read 8 consecutive bytes.